# Pendulum attached to a cart: is momentum conserved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws

Both the cart and the pendulum have velocity=0 at time=0, pendulum is held at that angle θ and then released.Frictions are negligible.

Is there an axis along which linear momentum is conserved? I've tried writing the equations for x and y axis, considering the system cart+pendulum, and the sum of the forces is greater than zero so momentum shouldn't conserve along x or y axis

For the pendulum we have:
$$ Tcosθ-mg=ma_{1y}$$
$$-Tsinθ=ma_{1x}
$$
For the cart we have:
$$R_ncosθ-Tcosθ+N-Mg=Ma_{2y} $$
$$-R_nsinθ+Tsinθ=Ma_{2x}$$

Summing the equations we get:
$$-R_nsinθ=Ma_{2x}+ma_{1x}$$
$$R_ncosθ-Mg-mg+N=Ma_{2y}+ma_{1y}$$
both differ from zero so momentum isn't conserved

I can't really find an axis where momentum is conserved

[image]

Comment: If your system consists of the cart, pendulum and the Earth, momentum is conserved in all axes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your equations. The problem is that you haven't completely analyzed them.

First, the force $R_n$ is zero. A string dangling from the ceiling does not produce an *upward* force on the ceiling. The entire force on the ceiling is produced by the tension in the string, and that is already included in your calculations. There is no reason to add an extra force $R_n$ in the opposite direction. Once you get rid of this non-existent force, you see that momentum is conserved in the horizontal direction. So that takes care of that.

(Perhaps you introduced $R_n$ because you thought there needed to be a reaction force. Remember how action-reaction pairs work -- if the string exerts a tension force $T$ on the ceiling, then the ceiling exerts a reaction force $R = -T$ *on the string*. If you decide to analyze the forces on the string, you should include $R$. But it is not a force on the ceiling.)

In the vertical direction, the explanation is a little different. You have left out one major mass from your analysis of vertical momentum -- the earth! If you do not include the earth, then the momentum of your system is not conserved, which is OK, because there are external forces (gravity and $N$) on the system.

But if you do want to include the earth in your system, then momentum will be conserved, as follows.

The earth experiences three forces here. First, there is a normal force from contact with the cart. This is the reaction force to the $N$ in your equations, so the value is $-N$. Additionally, the earth experiences a gravitational attraction to the masses of the cart and pendulum. These forces are the reaction forces to the $Mg$ and $mg$ of your equations. The net force on the earth is $Mg + mg - N$ and so we have one more equation:

$$Mg + mg - N = M_ea_{ey}.$$

Adding this missing term to your "sum of all vertical forces" equation gives:

$$R_n \cos \theta = Ma_{1y} + ma_{2y} + M_ea_{ey}.$$

As discussed above, $R_n = 0$. So the change in vertical momentum is also zero, as long as you include the earth.

Comment: Thank you so much, so basically the error was considering Rn, I tought Rn was needed because I had imagined the ceiling would 'collapse' without that force

Comment: One last question if I may, we basically studied the system composed by pendulum+cart, but we could study the system of cart+string+pendulum, and add an equation for the string along y axis : Rncosθ-mg=0   since the string is massless, and by adding all the equations, the one of the string doesn't make any difference for the system since its forces balance out. Is that right?

Comment: The string should be considered an idealized gadget for transmitting forces. A massless object is a little hard to handle. How do you calculate $a$ if $a = F/m$?

Comment: A "massless string" is obviously an idealization, but yeah, it doesn't contribute to the momentum of the system because it has no mass.

If you are serious about analyzing the string you should give it a mass. Otherwise it will be hard to describe the forces that make it move. In general, analysis of massive strings is beyond the scope of an introductory mechanics course. In a more advanced mechanics course you might study strings with masses and how they sag under their own weight, etc.

Comment: Thank you to everyone, you really helped me solve the doubt I had

Answer (score 4):

The horizontal forces on the cart are the horizontal component of $T$. The horizontal forces on the pendulum are the horizontal component of $T$. The cart and pendulum are parts of the system. These forces are internal forces. They are equal and opposite. They sum to $0$. The horizontal component of momentum of the system is conserved. The horizontal component momentum of the cart is equal and opposite to the horizontal component momentum of the pendulum.

Vertical forces on the cart are the vertical component of $T$, gravity, and the reaction force of the rollers. Vertical forces on the pendulum are the vertical component of $T$ and gravity.

The cart has no vertical component of momentum. The total vertical force on the cart is $0$. Gravitational and reaction forces are external. $T$ is internal. Since the vertical component of $T$ is not 0, the net external vertical forces are not 0.

The pendulum has non-zero total vertical forces, and non-zero vertical component of momentum (except at certain instants). Gravity is external. $T$ is internal. The pendulum has non-zero external forces.

If you look at the system as a whole, you can add up the external forces. They do not add to $0$. If you look at the vertical momentum, it goes up and down.